# Глобальная переменная python

Tags: python, python-2.x, переменные, python-2.7, global-variables

У меня есть два пакета:

> Unloader.py

и

> GetRequest.py

В скрипте, реализованном в Unloader.py происходит вызов функции, которая находится в GetRequest.py. Кроме того, в Unloader.py объявлена глобальная переменная, которая используется в указанной выше функции из GetRequest.py. Но почему-то данная глобальная переменная оказывается невидимой:

```
NameError: global name 'countFailResponse' is not defined
```

Приведу пример

> Unloader.py:

```
global countNullResponse

response, isGetData = GetRequests.Request(query)
```

> GetRequest.py:

```
def Request(query):
    global countNullResponse
    countNullResponse += 1
```

Как поправить код так, чтобы `Request` видел глобальную переменную `countNullResponse`?

Comment: `global` тут не совсем так работает ) это переменная, объявленная в модуле (скрипте) на самом низком уровне (без отступов) и global используется внутри функций в том модулей для того чтобы можно было присвоить значение той переменной, ибо если не указать `global` просто создастся новая переменная в области видимости функции. Подробности и больше примеров думаю щас расскажет @jfs )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ключевое слово `global` создано для того, чтобы обращаться к глобальной переменной модуля, вместо того, чтобы создавать локальную переменную в функции с таким же именем.

Предположим у нас в модуле есть переменная `countNullResponse`. Если мы попробуем написать внутри какой-либо функции `countNullResponse += 1`, то мы получим ошибку типа `NameError`, потому что пайтон будет искать данную переменную в локальном неймспейсе, то есть в неймспейсе функции. Чтобы обратиться к глобальной переменной и было создано ключевое слово `global`:

```
countNullResponse = 0

def Request(query):
    global countNullResponse
    countNullResponse += 1
    return countNullResponse, True

response, isGetData = Request('some url')

print(response, isGetData)
```

Если же вы хотите получать `countNullResponse`, но при этом не хотите хранить всё в одном модуле, то я предлагаю вам перенести эту переменную в другой модуль.

То есть, ваш `GetResponse` может иметь следующий вид:

```
countNullResponse = 0

def Request(query):
    global countNullResponse
    result = Connect(query)
    countNullResponse += 1
    return countNullResponse, result
```

А модуль `Unlodaer` - так:

```
from GetResponse import *

response, isGetData = Request(query)
```